# Did custom conventions make it into Entity Framework Core 3?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF6 ModelBuilder had a "Conventions" property. Has this functionality been added in any way to EF Core 3?

I have found this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/214 which is still open so I'm guessing it didn't ever get implemented? But just wanted to make sure.